# Why does my loop only append the last item from a list?

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, for-loop

I am trying to extract an element from a list and append it to a CSV file.

`json_response` is a list containing data on Twitter users who follow two politicians. For the first politician there are 5 tweets/users and for the second politician 13 tweets/users as can be seen from the structure of `json_response`. I want to extract the `description` for each user which is contained in `['includes']['users']`. However, my function only extracts the last `description` 5/5 user and 13/13 user for each politician.

My knowledge regarding JSON-like objects is limited.

```
print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))  # look at json_response object.
[
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "2877379617",
                "created_at": "2021-03-25T12:11:14.000Z",
                "id": "1375057688355336195",
                "text": "@prettynobodyco She blocked me in 2015 - for pointing out that Tim Kaine enables sexual assault in the military and the evidence was his killing of the MJIA and publicly stated that Military commanders should remain in charge of military rape cases. She's Tanden level awful. Congrats!"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1265018154444562440",
                "created_at": "2021-03-22T19:48:59.000Z",
                "id": "1374085719472361474",
                "text": "@MehcatCat @AlasscanIsBack @PattyArquette @timkaine Funny, they blocked me. \ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "2378324935",
                "created_at": "2021-03-07T21:32:13.000Z",
                "id": "1368675879312887810",
                "text": "@DrWinarick @KatieOGrady4 I apologize for any drama. Katie O Grady blocked me because we had a disagreement about Tim Kaine on one of your older posts. I guess I can't please everyone haha. :/"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "821870502943817729",
                "created_at": "2021-02-12T23:53:59.000Z",
                "id": "1360376637385244673",
                "text": "She blocked me a long ass time ago when I asked her why we shoulf care about Tim Kaine's personal view on abortion if it didn't impact legislation"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "16_1341045032732770306"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "17232340",
                "created_at": "2020-12-21T15:37:07.000Z",
                "id": "1341045038420275205",
                "text": "@DSingh4Biden @moomintroll8 @timkaine @GovernorVA That's why I replied to you. She blocked me previously, for what silliness I can't remember. Tough being a troll AND a snowflake!"
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media_key": "16_1341045032732770306",
                    "type": "animated_gif"
                }
            ],
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-11-15T02:23:57.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "2877379617",
                    "name": "Laura Saylor",
                    "username": "lauraleesaylor"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-05-25T20:33:36.000Z",
                    "description": "Weird Writer & Lunatic Linguist\nWicked Witch of the East\nshe/her",
                    "id": "1265018154444562440",
                    "name": "Zauberkind",
                    "username": "Zauberkind2"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2014-03-08T07:22:31.000Z",
                    "description": "#Resist, #BLM, #Vaxxed, liberal, autistic, kidney transplant survivor, political nerd, mental health advocate, fighter for equality, truth, justice, etc.",
                    "id": "2378324935",
                    "name": "Trevor \"Trev\" McKee Achilles",
                    "username": "MrTAchilles"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-01-19T00:02:52.000Z",
                    "description": "statist /  Progressive Gun Nut/ Single and hating it\n\n / \n\nstraight????? /\n\npronouns / brain worm survivor\n\n",
                    "id": "821870502943817729",
                    "name": "Puppet Enthusiast",
                    "username": "nihilisticpillo"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2008-11-07T15:09:46.000Z",
                    "description": "Liberal-Veteran-Dog Lover | Taste for irony, but in moderation | Humor is reason gone mad. ~Groucho Marx | I follow & unfollow back #VeteransResist #Resist",
                    "id": "17232340",
                    "name": "anti-Fascist Jim",
                    "username": "JimnBL"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1375057688355336195",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fos5vyedr54ngvtx3nuqvnx6pglrb1",
            "oldest_id": "1341045038420275205",
            "result_count": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "author_id": "737885223858384896",
                "created_at": "2021-03-26T21:56:02.000Z",
                "id": "1375567243082338314",
                "text": "@hogan_1969 @LindseyGrahamSC LOL She Blocked me.. could not admit the truth could she now. okay so where is her source for the shirts? and that is what he said. I (quote) We immediately surge the border all those seeking asylum. What about his lie about the cages? no Answer lol."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "847612931487416323",
                "created_at": "2021-03-26T21:55:24.000Z",
                "id": "1375567083791073283",
                "text": "@hogan_1969 @TeichTerry @thehill @LindseyGrahamSC @hogan_1969 just blocked me for showing her the actual numbers \ud83e\udd23\n\n#LiberalsHateFacts"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "18634205",
                "created_at": "2021-03-08T12:29:00.000Z",
                "id": "1368901564363051010",
                "text": "Huh.  Made me think if @LeaderMcConnell @LindseyGrahamSC @marcorubio @SenTedCruz feel trapped under the thumb of Trumpy.  And who else? @IvankaTrump? @MELANIATRUMP ? @DonaldJTrumpJr ? I\u2019d say Eric, but he blocked me."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "27327319",
                "created_at": "2021-03-02T11:53:16.000Z",
                "id": "1366718245521211393",
                "text": "@fedupinNHtoo @LindseyGrahamSC Exactly. I asked that question of a Republican on Facebook last night and she blocked me"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "917634626247647232",
                "created_at": "2021-02-28T18:16:45.000Z",
                "id": "1366089974907432961",
                "text": "@gop this is for you! @tedcruz @LindseyGrahamSC @MittRomney @mikepompeo\n#BitchyMcC blocked me!\ud83d\udc4d\nWatch \"Jack Off Jill - Hypocrite + lyrics\" on YouTube"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1231059979844456448",
                "created_at": "2021-02-26T04:25:49.000Z",
                "id": "1365156089554067459",
                "text": "@KelleyALynch1 @marwilliamson @therecount @LindseyGrahamSC She's fine with that just as she's fine with Biden's Nazis in Ukraine. She wants war with Russia, too. She blocked me for this tweet because she couldn't even condemn Biden's Nazis in Ukraine. She's a fauxgressive warmonger, a wolf in sheep's clothing."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1315477593303310336",
                "created_at": "2021-02-23T00:00:41.000Z",
                "id": "1364002202843451399",
                "text": "@MistyKitty3 @BlairMurray83 @FrankAmari2 @LindseyGrahamSC \ud83e\udd23 Someone didn\u2019t like what I said and blocked me."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1069115263671562240",
                "created_at": "2021-02-22T04:36:06.000Z",
                "id": "1363709124891070467",
                "text": "@trinkity88 @LindseyGrahamSC Apparently, @Trinkitty88 blocked me because FACTS are TOO HARD to handle!\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23\ud83e\udd23"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1303321972227690496",
                "created_at": "2021-02-20T19:38:49.000Z",
                "id": "1363211526316969985",
                "text": "@horsin64 @GovMurphy @LindseyGrahamSC You blocked me because you\u2019re a nifkin. It\u2019s not cyber tough you Nancy I\u2019d say it to your face. American lives matter before anyone else. America first and you don\u2019t like it because you have trump derangement. You\u2019re a psycho"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "27943005",
                "created_at": "2021-02-19T20:00:38.000Z",
                "id": "1362854626924650497",
                "text": "@TonyRom31334975 @staceyabrams @AnnaForFlorida @LindseyGrahamSC The guy blocked me on Twitter and had to unblock me after the Knight First Amendment Institute sued him and won&gt; I am certain It won't talk to me, but imagine..hehe?!"
            },
            {
                "attachments": {
                    "media_keys": [
                        "3_1361344652264280068"
                    ]
                },
                "author_id": "1126249378279297027",
                "created_at": "2021-02-15T16:00:32.000Z",
                "id": "1361344654395011079",
                "text": "@Jamie1074 @Breaking911 You know what\n\nIt's funny that they blocked me because I actually did agree with them on Lindsey Graham...\n\nCome on, man !"
            },
            {
                "author_id": "1207432044390699008",
                "created_at": "2021-02-14T07:58:21.000Z",
                "id": "1360860918687559681",
                "text": "@LindseyGrahamSC I really don't know why you haven't blocked me yet. Pile of human shit. I just read a letter that John McCain wrote me and for some reason it made me think about you and what he would think about your behavior. I guarantee you'd be in for an ass whippin'. Dick."
            },
            {
                "author_id": "926909484",
                "created_at": "2021-02-13T20:53:03.000Z",
                "id": "1360693490880032770",
                "text": "@LadyReverbs @themariefonseca @styvanswift @LindseyGrahamSC Lady, you might be able to see Marie\u2019s tweets. She blocked me. She may call this a victory for Trump. The reality is that seven members of the @GOP voted to convict. They are the true patriots of the Republican Party."
            }
        ],
        "includes": {
            "media": [
                {
                    "media_key": "3_1361344652264280068",
                    "type": "photo",
                    "url": ""
                }
            ],
            "users": [
                {
                    "created_at": "2016-06-01T05:55:21.000Z",
                    "description": "Biden Inflation the worst in 30 years. His Handlers trying to Rebrand Brandon is Hilarious.",
                    "id": "737885223858384896",
                    "name": "Biden is a complete mess and you know it.",
                    "username": "zelda3024"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-03-31T00:54:05.000Z",
                    "description": "Love God, Love Family, Love Country, Love Freedom - if we put those things first everything else will be great. MAGA",
                    "id": "847612931487416323",
                    "name": "Joey Bagadonuts",
                    "username": "AmericanGr8ness"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-01-05T15:25:55.000Z",
                    "description": "small & local garlic farmer; independent American; old surfer dude; working to find and speak truth to power; \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8; mahalo and Maluhia",
                    "id": "18634205",
                    "name": "MacGregorGarlic",
                    "username": "MacGregorGarlic"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-03-28T22:53:28.000Z",
                    "description": "Let's Go Darwin!",
                    "id": "27327319",
                    "name": "Karen Kennedy",
                    "username": "KayKay68"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2017-10-10T06:15:18.000Z",
                    "description": "Mom\ud83d\udc95Cannactivist\ud83c\udf3fSecularHumanist\ud83c\udf10 BLM\u270a\ud83c\udfff\ud83c\udf08Ally\ud83e\udd8bCPTSD\u2695\ufe0f FTD\ud83e\udd14MeToo\ud83c\udf38ProChoice\ud83d\udc93CRPS\ud83d\ude23ClimateChange\ud83c\udf0e DACA\ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf2AdoptDontShop\ud83d\udc3e#Steelers \ud83d\udda4\ud83d\udc9b #Vaxxed2TheMax\u270a\ud83d\udc9a",
                    "id": "917634626247647232",
                    "name": "Raven The Hemptress #LegalizeGlobally\ud83d\udc9a\ud83c\udf3f\u267f",
                    "username": "Kraven_Raven24"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-02-22T03:35:56.000Z",
                    "description": "Monetarism is the underlying cause of our disease; human progress and peace through development is the cure. Eurasian integration will benefit all of humanity!",
                    "id": "1231059979844456448",
                    "name": "\ud83c\udd70pocalypsis \ud83c\udd70pocalypseos \u2014 BRI Is The Future",
                    "username": "apocalypseos"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-10-12T02:21:21.000Z",
                    "description": "Father of two beautiful boys. Believer in the Constitution of the United States. Protector of my own rights. #Meatatarian",
                    "id": "1315477593303310336",
                    "name": "\ud83e\udd85 Steven Duggin \u2665\ufe0f \ud83c\uddfa\ud83c\uddf8\ud83d\uddfd",
                    "username": "itsStevenDuggin"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2018-12-02T06:25:16.000Z",
                    "description": "",
                    "id": "1069115263671562240",
                    "name": "Barhag",
                    "username": "TheBarhag"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2020-09-08T13:19:17.000Z",
                    "description": "Not the liberals cup of tea",
                    "id": "1303321972227690496",
                    "name": "Christy",
                    "username": "Christy54177764"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2009-03-31T19:34:24.000Z",
                    "description": "NY-grown, FL-tanned, scribe, word nerd, TV junkie, game show champ, yenta, wife, twin mama, hot sauce collector, Bloody Mary maven &, says @NYPost, savvy gadfly",
                    "id": "27943005",
                    "name": "Lesley Abravanel",
                    "username": "lesleyabravanel"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-05-08T22:15:51.000Z",
                    "description": "\u2600\ufe0f I post Yuuko Aioi pictures daily \u2600\ufe0f\n\nI also like being wholesome, making new friends, posting about games, my everyday life, cats, NASCAR, good vibes, fumos!",
                    "id": "1126249378279297027",
                    "name": "Vaxen #DailyYuuko \u2603\ufe0f",
                    "username": "YuukoEnjoyer"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2019-12-18T22:47:10.000Z",
                    "description": "The Republican party is bad for America. The Conservatives are Trump bootlickers who are afraid to stand up to him. This great nation is in serious trouble.",
                    "id": "1207432044390699008",
                    "name": "Angry Patriot",
                    "username": "AngryPatriot20"
                },
                {
                    "created_at": "2012-11-05T05:19:37.000Z",
                    "description": "Employment lawyer. Represent employers and employees. 30 years ago, my mentor told me to seek the truth as a lawyer. Still do that. Tweets are not legal advice.",
                    "id": "926909484",
                    "name": "Alfred Southerland",
                    "username": "TexasEEOLaw"
                }
            ]
        },
        "meta": {
            "newest_id": "1375567243082338314",
            "next_token": "b26v89c19zqg8o3fosnr8q7zstmzppg3jgd1cvynkb919",
            "oldest_id": "1360693490880032770",
            "result_count": 13
        }
    }
]
```

When I run the for loop outside a function and `print(bio)` I can see that it loop through all users in `json_response`.

```
for each_dict in json_response:
    for dic in each_dict['includes']['users']:

        # 5. description
        if 'description' in dic:
            bio = dic['description']
        else:
            bio = " "

        print(bio)

Weird Writer & Lunatic Linguist
Wicked Witch of the East
she/her
#Resist, #BLM, #Vaxxed, liberal, autistic, kidney transplant survivor, political nerd, mental health advocate, fighter for equality, truth, justice, etc.
statist /  Progressive Gun Nut/ Single and hating it
 / 
straight????? /
pronouns / brain worm survivor

Liberal-Veteran-Dog Lover | Taste for irony, but in moderation | Humor is reason gone mad. 
~Groucho Marx | I follow & unfollow back #VeteransResist #Resist
Biden Inflation the worst in 30 years. His Handlers trying to Rebrand Brandon is Hilarious.
Love God, Love Family, Love Country, Love Freedom - if we put those things first everything else will be great. MAGA
small & local garlic farmer; independent American; old surfer dude; working to find and speak truth to power; ; mahalo and Maluhia
Let's Go Darwin!
MomCannactivistSecularHumanist BLM✊AllyCPTSD⚕️ FTDMeTooProChoiceCRPSClimateChange DACAAdoptDontShop#Steelers  #Vaxxed2TheMax✊
Monetarism is the underlying cause of our disease; human progress and peace through development is the cure. Eurasian integration will benefit all of humanity!
Father of two beautiful boys. Believer in the Constitution of the United States. Protector of my own rights. #Meatatarian
Not the liberals cup of tea
NY-grown, FL-tanned, scribe, word nerd, TV junkie, game show champ, yenta, wife, twin mama, hot sauce collector, Bloody Mary maven &, says @NYPost, savvy gadfly
☀️ I post Yuuko Aioi pictures daily ☀️
I also like being wholesome, making new friends, posting about games, my everyday life, cats, NASCAR, good vibes, fumos!
The Republican party is bad for America. The Conservatives are Trump bootlickers who are afraid to stand up to him. This great nation is in serious trouble.
Employment lawyer. Represent employers and employees. 30 years ago, my mentor told me to seek the truth as a lawyer. Still do that. Tweets are not legal advice.
```

The function `append_to_csv` should loop over `json_response` and append `description` to column `bio` in `bio_data.csv`.

```
# Create file
csvFile = open("bio_data.csv", "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

# Create headers for the data I want to save. I only want to save description/bio
csvWriter.writerow(
    ["bio"])
csvFile.close()

def append_to_csv(json_response, csvFile):
    
    # counter variable
    global bio
    counter = 0

    # open CSV file
    csvFile = open(csvFile, "a", newline="", encoding='utf-8')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

   
    for each_dict in json_response:
        for dic in each_dict['includes']['users']:

            # 1. description
            if 'description' in dic:
                bio = dic['description'] # if description extract descripton
            else:
                bio = " " # if no description fill row with NaN
       
        # assemble all data in a list
        res = [bio]


        # append the result to the CSV file
        csvWriter.writerow(res)

    # close CSV file
    csvFile.close()

    # print the number of tweets for this iteration
    print("# of bios added from this response", counter) 

append_to_csv(json_response, "bio_data.csv")
```

When I `print(df)` it becomes clear that the function `append_to_csv` only append the `description` for user 5/5 and user 13/13. Any suggestion as to what is wrong with `append_to_csv`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'path...\bio_data.csv')  # import bio_data as pandas

print(df)

         bio
0       Liberal-Veteran-Dog Lover | Taste for irony, but in moderation | Humor is reason gone mad. ~Groucho Marx | I follow & unfollow back #VeteransResist #Resist
1  Employment lawyer. Represent employers and employees. 30 years ago, my mentor told me to seek the truth as a lawyer. Still do that. Tweets are not legal advice.
```

Comment: Your loop simply makes a list out of the last entry, `es = [bio]` and do nothing with any of the others... not sure why you were expecting anything else. Probably, you want to create a list in that loop, appending each `bio` on every iteration to some list.

Comment: Or, potentially, do `csvWriter.writerow([bio])` on each iteration of the loop

Comment: i.e. basically indent those lines into the inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem relies in the `append_to_csv` function because of a wrong indentation.

Look at your code:

```py
for each_dict in json_response:
    for dic in each_dict['includes']['users']:

        if 'description' in dic:
            bio = dic['description']
        else:
            bio = " " 

    res = [bio]    # In the outer loop
    csvWriter.writerow(res)    # In the outer loop
```

Here, you iterate the whole `each_dict` before *writing* `res` in the csv. Therefore, the intermediate assignments in the `if/else` statement are meaningless but for the last iteration, where `bio` is assigned the description of the last element in `each_dict`.
Moving `res = [bio]` and `csvWriter.writerow(res)` in the inner loop should do the job, so that a csv row is written for every element `dic`:

```py
for each_dict in json_response:
    for dic in each_dict['includes']['users']:

        if 'description' in dic:
            bio = dic['description']
        else:
            bio = " " 

        res = [bio]    # In the inner loop
        csvWriter.writerow(res)    # In the inner loop
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the answer and explanation @s.dallapalma. The code works. Now my issue is to implement your solution in a nested loop... Different question somewhat same issue. If it has any interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658587/append-data-to-csv-using-a-nested-loop